How to Query a Table of Linked Lists with no List ID?
I have a postgres table that's effectively stores linked lists, but none
of the rows have a list identifier.  So it's hard to pick out lists from table,
other than to "hop" to each node.
create table exchange_history (
    curr_node_id integer,
    prev_node_id integer,   -- This is NULL for the first node in the list.
    description text        -- (Just an example)
)

How would I do the following:

Given a node id of a node in a list, how to select all the nodes of that list?
How to do so if given a description?
How to select them in the same order of the list?  Assuming that the node id value does not suggest an order in the list?
Also, if given a description found in a list, how to select all start nodes?

The table contains link lists, so there isn't multiple nodes having the same prev_node_id.
(This isn't homework or an interview question, I genuinely interested in knowing how to do this, but I also have some customer tables that I need to query that are effectively like this.)
Thanks.

1: Use a recursive CTE. 2: Use a recursive with an initial WHERE clause CTE. 3: Use a recursive CTE with a column derived from the recursion depth. 4: Use a trivial query: WHERE prev_node_id IS NULL AND description = ?.
